# Assign team members to groups to maximize outcome

Tags: graphs, combinatorics

Team A has 2 Spots

Team B has 1 Spot

Player 1: 10 Units when on team A, Can't work on team B

Player 2: 8 Units when on team A, Can't work on team B

Player 3: 9 Units when on team A, 2 Units when on team B

I'm trying to craft an algorithm that will maximize the total units of output between the two teams. I'm representing the teams and players as nodes in a graph and the number of units as edges.

I initially attempted a greedy algorithm which would choose the heaviest weighted edge possible. However, this results in players 1 and 3 on Team A with no one able to contribute to Team B.

How would I arrive at a more nuanced approach in which Team A would get players 1 and 2, and Team B would get player 3? Is this more of a graph theory or combinatorics problem? Or both?

Comment: $Cost(player,team)$ is the property we have to maximize for each team.

We should start with the team that has the lowest amount of resources.

$Cost(1,A)$ = 10, $Cost(1,B)$ = 0; 
$Cost(2,A)$ =   8, $Cost(2,B)$ = 0;
$Cost(3,A)$ =   9, $Cost(3,B)$ = 2;

Hence we go with B first and assign Player 3 to it. Then we get the respective cost for A.

Comment: @Sagnik I get that we want to optimize for this function but how can we generalize a solution for a variable number of teams and players?

Comment: Try to formulate a dynamic programming approach with the $Cost$ function.